# "Property 'bxSlider' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'" on Angular project

Tags: jquery, angular, npm, visual-studio-code, bxslider

im getting this error on an Angular project, im trying to use bxSlider, I followed the instructions on the official web page https://bxslider.com/ to install it, but it appears that VS Code (or Angular) is not recognizing the plugin.

To install it, I did the NPM method:

`npm install bxslider --save`

then I included the bxslider css and js script:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/bxslider/dist/jquery.bxslider.min.css">
<script src="/node_modules/bxslider/dist/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
```

and then in my component as soon as I reference it:

```
$('.slider').bxSlider();
```

I get the error: Property 'bxSlider' does not exist on type 'JQuery'.

The weird thing is that if I do this on navigator console (chrome):

```
$('.slider').bxSlider();
```

it works just fine, I can see the empty bxSlider, but VS Code is still showing me the error and ng serve command throws the same error.

In package.json, under dependencies, it appears

```
"bxslider": "^4.2.14",
```

and in package-lock.json:

```
 "bxslider": {
      "version": "4.2.14",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/bxslider/-/bxslider-4.2.14.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-7/OV7Jxe8yBS/7tOcxg2hYTPmACFMU1rRs3xqoljjFX/rSgMFVX0dzFqxZHWvUgl0+9TryNy5vhufB/499heFQ=="
    },
```

I dont know if I have to put the path to bxslider on angular.json, but I did it:

```
            "styles": [
              "src/assets/css/styles.css",
              "./node_modules/bxslider/dist/jquery.bxslider.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/bxslider/dist/jquery.bxslider.min.js"
            ]
```

still, no luck.

I already tried the CDN method and download the zip file to my project, Im getting the same error.

```
Angular CLI: 12.2.1
Node: 14.17.1
Package Manager: npm 6.14.13
```

Comment: Sounds to me like you're trying to use bxSlider before it has finished loading. You could try running `$.bxSlider` in the callback of `window.onload`. Alternatively, make sure you're importing bxSlider before your script which attempts to use it (the import `<script>` should physically come before the script which uses it).

Comment: thanks for the comment, Im new to Angular and web dev in general, Im still doing tutorials, in this case Im doing exactly what is being shown on the tutorial, the call to bxslider is on ngOnInit() method, the project is not even compiling after I reference bxSlider. btw I can perfectly get DOM elements with JQuery on that method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because type Jquery< HTMLElemen t> doesn't know bxSlider.

Try casting it to any type

```
($('.slider') as any).bxSlider();
```

or

```
(<any>$('.slider')).bxSlider();
```

Comment: omg, thanks, that works great, any clue why the guy in the tutorial don't needed this workaround? I write the exact same code (tutorial is from like 2 years ago, so he used different versions).

Comment: Not entirely sure what he's doing. Is he using Angular or a Typescript project? If so, i'd say the difference lies in the tsconfig.json file. Not entirely sure. Anyway for the most part, avoid using "any" type as much as you can, since its considered a bad practive.
Also, allow me to suggest, try to explore ng-bootstrap or Angular Material components. Ng-bootstrap particularly is easy to use.
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples
Keep up the good work!

Comment: Thank you for the reply, André, and the recommendation about 'any type' and ng-bootstrap. Tutorial is about Angular, JQuery, NodeJs, etc. I dont think he set up anything in tsconfig.json, maybe off screen?.